# What to call this "partial mean" of a sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics, terminology, markov-chains

I have a three sequences of draws of a random variable (from three MCMC chains). I wish to illustrate the convergence of these chains in the following way. Let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be one of the chains. I construct a new chain $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^n$ where $Y_k=\frac1k \sum_{i=1}^k X_i$ for all $k$. I have a nice plot showing the values $Y_i$ for each chain quickly converging to the same value. I find myself wanting to say: "the partial sums of the chains converge", but that's not right, because the $Y_i$ aren't partial sums -- they are "partial averages", or something. Is there a particular term I should use here?

Comment: I would have thought *cumulative averages* or *incremental averages* or  *partial averages* would be clear enough provided you state what they mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think *cumulative sums* and *cumulative means* are the terms you're
looking for.

Let's use repeated tosses of a fair coin $(0 = \text{Tail}, 1 = \text{Head})$ -- only trivially a Markov Chain, but good enough to illustrate the ideas and terminology.
Say we have $X_1, \dots, X_n;$ let the 'cumulative sums' be $S_n$ and the
'cumulative means' be $Y_n.$ Then a plot of the $Y_n$ against $n$ (often called
a 'trace') shows the convergence to $1/2.$

In R statistical software, the function `cumsum` finds the $S_n$'s:

```
 set.seed(1220);  m = 10^4;  n = 1:m
 x = sample(0:1, m, rep=T)
 s = cumsum(x);  y = s/n                     # cumulative sums and means
 plot(n, y, ylim=c(.3,.7), lwd=2, type="l")  # plot trace ('ell' not 'one')
 abline(h=1/2, col="green3")
```

[image]

```
tab = cbind(n, x, s, y); head(tab); tail(tab)
     n x s         y
[1,] 1 0 0 0.0000000
[2,] 2 0 0 0.0000000
[3,] 3 0 0 0.0000000
[4,] 4 0 0 0.0000000
[5,] 5 1 1 0.2000000
[6,] 6 0 1 0.1666667
             n x    s         y
[9995,]   9995 0 4942 0.4944472
[9996,]   9996 1 4943 0.4944978
[9997,]   9997 0 4943 0.4944483
[9998,]   9998 0 4943 0.4943989
[9999,]   9999 1 4944 0.4944494
[10000,] 10000 1 4945 0.4945000
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but people do a lot of work on this type of thing (for instance in Finance), the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) has a bunch of stuff on various approaches to a rolling mean.

Comment: A difference is that running averages tend to include a recent sequence of fixed length (or time span) whereas the cumulative means considered here all go back (all the way) to the beginning of the data sequence.